# Azure Customised Global Admin role

Tags: json, azure, azure-active-directory, cloud, roles

I would like to create an Azure customised role (in JSON format) with Global Admin perms but with a limitation to creating resources. Anyone can help with that?

(or a more relevant built-in Azure role?)

Much appreciated!

Not an expert of Azure/JSON

Answer (score 0):

By default, [global-administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#global-administrator) built-in role won't assign RBAC roles to Azure resources. You can see the same mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/elevate-access-global-admin#how-does-elevated-access-work).

> Azure AD and Azure resources are secured independently from one another. That is, Azure AD role assignments do not grant access to Azure resources, and Azure role assignments do not grant access to Azure AD.

If you just want the role not to create resources, you would need to clone all perms  of global administrator & [Owner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#owner) roles & individually exclude create actions like `Microsoft.Compute/*/create`, `Microsoft.Storage/*/read` etc., in `notActions` list

Comment: exactly this is what I want to do. Is there a list of "create actions" somewhere?

Comment: Basically, I want to create a "limited contributor" role, with the limitations of create new resources